# Bounds on the mills ratio

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities

How do I show the following bounds on the mills ratio :

$\frac{1}{x}- \frac{1}{x^3} < \frac{1-\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)} < \frac{1}{x}- \frac{1}{x^3} +\frac{3}{x^5} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $   for $ \ \ \ x>0$    where $\Phi()$ is the CDF of the Normal distribution , and $\phi()$ is the density function of the Normal distribution ?

Also , is there a similar bound when $x < 0$ ?

I am aware of the proof of the fact that the mills ratio is bounded below by $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ and above by $\frac{1}{x}$ , but I am unable to prove this inequality .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sketch and a link for how I prove it. Let
  $$ f(x) = - \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{3}{x^5}\right) \phi(x) .$$

Now show (lemma): $\frac{df}{dx} = \left(1 + \frac{15}{x^6}\right)\phi(x)$.

(To prove this, use that $\frac{d\phi}{dx} = - x \phi(x)$, the product rule, and some cancellation.)

Now suppose $x > 0$:

\begin{align*}
  1 - \Phi(x) &= \int_{t=x}^{\infty} \phi(x) dx  \\
              &\leq \int_{t=x}^{\infty} \left(1 + \frac{15}{x^6}\right) \phi(x) dx  \\
              &=     \lim_{t\to\infty} f(t) - f(x)  \\
              &=   - f(x)  \\
              &= \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{3}{x^5} \right) \phi(x) .
\end{align*}

Using the next term in the series gives $f(x) = -\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{3}{x^5} - \frac{15}{x^7}\right)\phi(x)$ and $\frac{df}{dx} = \left(1 - \frac{105}{x^8}\right)\phi(x)$. Notice because of the alternating positive/negative terms, $\frac{df}{dx}$ is now $\phi$ times something less than one, so plugging it into the same proof gives a **lower** bound on $1 - \Phi(x)$. I have a [blog post on the general form of this](https://bowaggoner.com/blog/2018/03-17-gaussian-tails/index.html) (sorry to not point you to a more formal reference).

Answer (score 3):

This is a special case of [Proposition 1.3](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f405/ae797cb1994778036b7fdc101b5367b34f9d.pdf?_ga=2.80057687.1110939797.1556295006-729367919.1556295006).

The case $x<0$ obtains from this by symmetry: $\Phi(-z)=1-\Phi(z)$ and $\phi(-z)=\phi(z)$ for all $z$.

Comment: +1  Could you please include a proof of Proposition 1.3 for the sake of completeness .

Comment: @John : The proof of the identity from which your inequalities immediately follow is the following sentence on page 3 of the referenced paper: "Identity (1.4) is immediate from the recurrence relation [...], which in turn is obtained by integration by parts".